# Permissions Issue pointing Sonarr to HDD

Tags: permissions, hard-drive

I had Sonarr working 100% on my desktop which was running Windows 7.

I have one 60gb SSD solely for the OS and a 4TB HDD for all my media.

Since switching to Ubuntu 16.04 I'm unable to point Sonarr to my 4TB hdd as the disk isn't showing in "Import Existing Series On Disk" although it is in "My Computer"

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: How do you know it's a permissions issue? Did you get a specific error message that told you it was? What's the filesystem on the HDD? Is it mounted by `fstab`?

Comment: To be honest I don't but how can I access it no problem through the explorer but not Sonarr? The filesystem is NTFS. Should I format it to ext?

Comment: I don't know Sonarr... aren't you able to browse to the mountpoint through it?

Comment: That's the problem I can't get past /media/(username) - It doesn't show up

Comment: ahhh it seems Sonarr runs as a service... does it have a user in `/etc/passwd`? (have a look in the file for it - don't edit the file). If you don't see anything obvious there you could try running `top` or `ps -aux` to spot the process owner while it's running (you could try `ps -aux | grep sonarr`) You may need to grant the Sonarr user an ACL on `/media/$USER/`or run it as another user

Comment: did you use the site instructions to set up autostart with systemd? It might help if you add details of your Sonarr setup procedure to your question

Comment: to add information, you can [edit] your question or use http://paste.ubuntu.com if it's too long or only needed temporarily

Comment: Yeah I followed these instructions - https://thisisforsomething.com/guide/guide-to-plex-media-server-on-ubuntu-server-16-04/

I'm really lost with this as I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

Also, I'm only new to Linux so I don't know how to run the commands you are saying sorry :(

Comment: 1. Create a new user to run the Sonarr service      - 

sudo adduser --disabled-password --system --home /opt/ProgramData/sonarr --gecos "Sonarr Service" --group sonarr

Should I create a new user called "Sonarr" or should I use my username?

Comment: no don't use your username... did you already run that command to create the `sonarr` user?

Comment: Yes I ran it when following the tutorial. How can I remove EVERYTHING got to do with Sonarr and start fresh?

Comment: I don't think you did anything wrong - you might just need to grant the sonarr user permission on the mountpoint using ACLs... in a terminal, you would run the command `sudo setfacl -m u:sonarr:rx /media/$USER`

Comment: I tried that but now I'm getting 'deb' errors in terminal. I think I should just reinstall Ubuntu :(

Comment: I deleted the sonarr.service file and now the deb errors have stopped. Currently running AtoMiC ToolKit. I'll keep you posted

Comment: YESSSSSSSSSSSS!!!!!!!!!!! I got it sorted. I followed this procedure with AtoMic https://www.htpcbeginner.com/install-sonarr-on-ubuntu/, uninstalled Sonarr and reinstalled and now it picks up my 4TB :)

Thank you so much for all your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I don't seem to have done anything at all, but happy you fixed it :) Would you like to add an answer in the Answer section below to help future users?

Answer (score 1):

Ran Atomic Toolkit found here - https://www.htpcbeginner.com/install-sonarr-on-ubuntu/

Went through the process of uninstalling/reinstalling the Sonarr service using the toolkit.

Quick reboot and my drives were accessible